# sortable.js not working in JSP pages

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to use this little script I found [here](http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/), but for some reason it's not working and I can't figure out why.

My head tags in browse.jsp :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Parcourir les livres</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/sortable.js"></script>
</head>
```

My table, in the same page of course:

```
    <table class="sortable" id="sortabletable">          
            <thead>
                    <th>Aperçu</th>
                    <th>Titre</th>
                    <th>Éditeur</th>
                    <th>Auteur</th>
                    <th>Prix</th>
            </thead>
            <%
            for(Livre livre : livres){
                 %>
                <tr>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td><% out.println(livre.getNom()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(livre.getEditeur()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(livre.getAuteur()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(livre.getPrix()); %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
  </table>
```

I don't think it comes from the src path since I tried to put the .js in the same directory as my page. Anyway here's my [tree](http://tof.canardpc.com/view/419988d0-9a5c-4bd1-b3b2-b5a94c4b3f8a.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, what does your error console say?

Comment: Well, nothing. The script just acts like it's not here.

Comment: Are there any functions that you need to invoke to make it work? I'm not familiar with the script you're using.

Comment: According to the script author no I don't. Just put the script and add a class and id attribute to the table you want to sort...

Comment: Strange. You could try putting the sort script at the bottom of the page, but other than that, I don't know what to suggest. Sorry :C

Comment: It seems you were right because if I put the script in the page it works ! I guess I suck at finding the good path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your path to the javascript is wrong. Without knowing your application I cannot give you the exact path.

Its probably `JS/sortable.js` or `../JS/sortable.js`. Files within the WEB-INF directory can't be accessed directly. So you don't have to figure out the path from your project structure. You have to figure it out from the pathes at runtime.

You could try to use an absolute path as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JS/sortable.js" />
```

Comment: I tried all of you three pathes but it's not working... Even though path seems good with the getContextPath() method which gives me src="/Javaxia/JS/sortable.js". Anyway I included a screen of my project in Netbeans in my first post.

Comment: Try the absolute path. If that one is not working please post the complete path of the page that is calling the javascript and the complete path to the javascript.

Comment: Try to call the full path you see in rendered page into your browser. If that path is working its probably a usage problem.

Comment: You should check if the javascript is deployed at all. Try renaming the folder to "js" and make the path lower case. What application server are you using? Can you access the css files?

Comment: Lower case trick isn't working. I use Glassfish 3.1.1 and it seems I can't access the CSS files either. My project may be messed up...